# Setting PYTHONPATH on ubuntu fails with 'not a valid identifier'

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to set the Pythonpath on a Ubuntu server without luck.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
```

This executes without any errors, however when I want to double check the variable.

```
export $PYTHONPATH
```

I get this:

```
-bash: export: `:/home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api': not a valid identifier
```

I can't find anything on google. What is causing this?

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with Python, and everything to do with bash. I'll edit the tags for you, but surely you can see that yourself?

Comment: Exporting the same variable a second time does nothing. If you want to verify that it is properly exported, check that it is properly visible in a subshell, e.g. with `bash -c ’echo ”$PYTHONPATH”’`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error shown is because you are exporting the *value* of the shell variable `PYTHONPATH` which is the path that you specified. Do this instead:

```
export PYTHONPATH
```

which tells the shell to export the variable named PYTHONPATH, not its value.

If you simply want to see the value of the variable use

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

instead of `export`.